# Siteminde policy serveur capacity

Tags: authentication, saml-2.0, federated-identity, siteminder

I would like to know what is the capacity of authentication/ second a day.
This information will help me to do some capacity planning.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Does [this document](https://techdocs.broadcom.com/us/en/symantec-security-software/identity-security/siteminder/12-8/implementing/implementing-siteminder/web-services-security-capacity-planning.html) help? I googled for "siteminder capacity planning"...

Comment: Hello 
Thank you so much. I have read the document but don't get the breaking point to know if it's needed to add a new server.
 I will check it again an try to see if I find an answer.
Maybe I didn't read well and misunderstood.

Comment: The problem with your question for all of StackOverflow is that just Like Broadcom can't really effectively answer your question in their capacity planning guide, we can't either. Authentications per second are a test of the **system** as a whole. Your CPUs and CPU counts, network latency to identity store (LDAP?), identity store indexes, etc., all play a part. Anything that someone else can give you can **only** be an intelligent guess. Your best bet is to test it yourself, in your own performance testing environment, that replicates your production (or has a similar "scale").

Comment: Thank you I totally understand your answer the problem is that I am not having access so I was presuming that the vendor or some had test it.
I am doing a reverse engineering I know that I have 8 policy servers and 3 access gateway. So from those info I am trying to get an answer.
I will keep looking tho thank you.